# QtSerialPort/QSerialPort and QSerialPort were not found on raspberry pi

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qmake

I tried methods from:

- [QtSerialPort QSerialPort no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206351/qtserialport-qserialport-no-such-file-or-directory)

Tried to include `QtSerialPort/QSerialPort` or `QSerialPort` like this, not works for me.

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "serialctrl.h"
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
// #include <QSerialPort>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

And these package were installed already:

- libqt5serialport5
- libqt5serialport5-dev
- libudev-dev

I checked the file path from my friend's Pi which works without error is `/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtSerialPort/`, and the files exist in the same path on mine but Qt creator still shows the "can't found" message. And the `Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: serialport`.

Same code compiled fine on my Windows 10.

Also, my friend's pi has a weird problem is the `QSerialPort` including only works(I mean included without error) under one specific user, this makes me wondering maybe this only works for the user who executed the `apt install <some-qt-pack>`?

---

### about qt

- Qt version: Qt 5.11.3 (GCC 8.3.0, 32 bit)
- Qt creator: 4.8.2

### about my device

- System: `Raspberry Pi OS`
- device: `Raspberry Pi 4b (8G)`
- /proc/version: `Linux version 5.10.63-v7l (root@raspberrypi) (gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Raspbian) 2.31.1) #6 SMP Mon Oct 25 20:42:31 CST 2021`

PS: the kernel I use was compiled manually on my raspberry pi by following this [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html).

### the pro file of my qt project.

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += serialport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

#TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    serial.cpp \
    serialctrl.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
    serial.h \
    serialctrl.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui \
    serialctrl.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc

#INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtSerialPort/
```

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: I installed it with apt. @eyllanesc

Comment: Please give me the result of `qmake --version` and `qtchooser -print-env` commands on your Pi.

Comment: @Farshid616 Sorry for replying so late. After that, my street was blocked for a month because of the covid. I don't have any Pi at home. It might be impossible for me to get another Pi in this year. :-(